# Returning random values using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I've loaded in a CSV with the column **name, active and email**. I've converted this into a pandas dataframe.

I'm trying to return a random name from the data frame using random.choice(), but I'm returning a sequence of letters, not full names.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import random as rand

people = pd.read_csv('persons.csv')
    
for name in people['name']:
    print(rand.choice(name))
```

**my output:**

```
i
m
d
n
i
c
u
o
c
v
L
a
 
V
a
t
```

Comment: Suggestion: skip the `for` loop and use [`Series.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html).

Comment: agree with @BigBen. pandas is a big library so if you search carefully enough, you can do almost any kind of data manipulation or selection without having to use other libraries

Comment: It would help if you provide a sample for the dataframe

Comment: Thank @BigBen, series sample is just what I need. Do you know how to return random participants that have not been previously matched using a for loop?